# What is involved in “shnayim mikro v'echod targum” for someone travelling from outside the land to Israel when the sedrahs are different?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eretz-yisrael, travel, parsha-torah-portion

What are the principles involved in “shnayim mikro v'echod targum” for someone travelling from outside the land to Israel when the sedrahs read in those places are different. (I have already asked my Rov for specific guidance; this question is to uncover the principles involved).

For example someone travelling to Israel this week and returning before Shabbos 16 May 15.

2 May 15 Sedrahs outside Israel – Acharei Mos, Kedoshim

2 May 15 Sedrah in Israel – Emor

My assumption is that this person must prepare three sedrahs otherwise he will have lost Acharei Mos, Kedoshim.

9 May 15  Sedrah outside Israel – Emor

9 May 15  Sedrah in Israel – Behar

My assumption is that since this person will be in Israel he must prepare Behar.

16 May 15  Sedrah outside Israel – Behar, Bechukosai

16 May 15  Sedrah in Israel – Bechukosai

[Orach Chayim 285 (1) MB [1]](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=127) says that a person should not go ahead with his “shnayim mikro v'echod targum” as he has to finish his parshiyos with the community as the [gemoro says Brochos 8a](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9D#cite_ref-1)

"אמר רב הונא בר יהודה אמר רבי אמי: לעולם ישלים אדם פרשיותיו עם הצבור שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום, ואפילו 'עטרות ודיבון', שכל המשלים פרשיותיו עם הצבור מאריכין לו ימיו ושנותיו"

This person will have prepared Behar in the week of 9th May; does he have to repeat it in the week of 16th May so  that *he finishes his parshiyos with the community*?